# Linking trouble with wininit library (LNK1120)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, wininet, lnk2019

I use Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7. I have this function:

```
void send(char* log, char* pas, char* ser, char* plik)
{   
    HINTERNET hInternet;
    HINTERNET hFtpSession;
    hInternet = InternetOpenA(NULL,INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,NULL,NULL,0);
    hFtpSession = InternetConnectA(hInternet,ser,INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,log,pas, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0,0 );
    FtpPutFileA(hFtpSession, "WMM.txt", plik, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
}
```

It didn't work:

> 1. error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl send(class
>    std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class
>    std::allocator >,class std::basic_string<char,struct
>    std::char_traits,class std::allocator >,class
>    std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class
>    std::allocator >,class std::basic_string<char,struct
>    std::char_traits,class std::allocator >)"
>    (?send@@YAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@000@Z)
>    referenced in function _main

> 2)fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved
> externals

I googled for solution and found this:
Add this `#pragma comment(lib, "wininet")` to your code or add wininet.lib in your project properties: Linker->Input

I do this and still not working - I get identical errors like earlier.
Have you got any idea what I should do for resolved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unresolved external symbol error is for a function like this

```
void send(std::string log, std::string pas, std::string ser, std::string plik)
```

but the function you've shown us is like this

```
void send(char* log, char* pas, char* ser, char* plik)
```

I would *guess* that you have written the first version in your header file, and the second version in your source file. You need to be consistent, one version or the other, not both.